# What are some conventions defining a connection to an external API using NextJS 13's App Directory

Tags: authentication, next.js, airtable

**I want to connect to the Airtable API using NextJS13 & it's new App directory paradigm.**

I don't want to have to authenticate the request every time I make it. Airtable provides an SDK which offers an API for setting up authentication & connecting to the various tables in the database.

Does anyone have opinions or advice on a better way to do it, or even the supported way to do this, in the new App directory paradigm.

When using the "pages" paradigm, I would typically create the connection using their SDK in a custom file in /utils/airtable.ts. Then I would import the connection anywhere I needed to make a call to their API.

---

I'm also considering that the Airtable SDK might not be as up to date as the latest React & Next conventions - so I'm also open to conventions for setting something like this up not using the Airtable SDK.

Comment: I would personally do it the way you described. I'd create a `service/airtable.ts` that exports the configured client then call it in an async func on whichever pages you want to display the data. Using the new server-side data fetching will hide your key. => https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/data-fetching/fetching